# MS Form Recognizer - Unable to find my model after training. Did I miss any step?

Tags: forms, ocr, azure-form-recognizer

Referring to the guide in link below

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/label-tool

I have been able to upload my documents and have my model successfully trained (with model id)
[image: model successfully trained]

But when I try to call the service via REST API, I am unable to find my model.

> https://{endpoint}/formrecognizer/v1.0-preview/custom/models

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{
  "models": []
}
```

Am I missing any step? Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

When calling the API you need to call the Form Recognizer v2.0 API to find your model - https://{endpoint}/formrecognizer/v2.0-preview/custom/models/{modelId}